# Ordinals: Is $0^\beta = 0?$

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

Let $\beta$ be a (non-empty) ordinal.

Is $0^\beta = 0?$ Or is it $1$?

My definition is the following: let $\alpha, \beta$ ordinals

$\alpha^0= 1$, $\alpha^{\beta+1} = \alpha^\beta \alpha, \alpha^\beta = \bigcup_{\eta < \beta} \alpha^\eta$ if $\beta$ is a non-zero limit ordinal.

From this definition, it would seem that $0^0 = 1$, $0^1 = 1. 0=0, \dots$

$$0^\omega= \bigcup_{\eta <\omega}\alpha^\eta= 1$$???

These results don't seem to make sense.

Comment: Yes, the definition is "wrong", i.e., doesn't work "correctly"  with base $0$. we want $0^0=1$ and $0^\beta=0$ otherwise. Taking the supremum instead of the limit fails precisely here where the powers are decreasing.

Comment: You should redefine $\alpha^\beta$ for $\beta$ limit as $\bigcup_{0<\gamma<\beta}\alpha^\gamma$, so $0^0=1$ but $0^\tau=0$ for all nonzero $\tau$.

Comment: Thanks both! This makes way more sense.

Comment: Oh, this is definitely a duplicate... I'll find it in a bit.

Comment: That was *very* hard to find: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/156458/whats-the-definition-of-limit-of-setsesp-ordinals-in-set-theory (and also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1023974/is-0-omega-1)